# Перекомпилировать swf файл

Tags: swf, flash, actionscript

Есть файл swf формата. 
Можно ли его декомпилировать, исправить в нем одну ссылку и обратно скомпилировать?

Пробовал через программу Sothink. Но она только декомпилирует, и обратно в swf собирать не умеет. Преобразовывал в fla, хотел потом скомпилировать во флеше, но компилятор выдал 59 ошибок. 
Как можно реализовать это?

Answer (score 2):

Вот [спецификация формата файла SWF](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf-file-format-spec.pdf), где пишут, что строки пишутся в UTF8, а сам файл компрессируется zlib'ом. Может, попробуете раззиповать его, и тогда строка ссылки будет видна открытым текстом, а при замене её на другую не вылезет никаких ошибок? Просто предположение, не проверял, к сожалению.

Comment: Предположение рабочее (недавно были длительные романтические отношения со сборкой swf8 почти руками), однако стоит учесть

 - перед распаковкой прочитать сигнатуру и заголовок (пакуется все остальное)
 - либо должны совпасть размеры файлов, либо придется менять размер файла в заголовке
 - если в заголовк изменить размер, а сигнатуру поставить FWS - можно остаток не упаковывать, т.е. превратить `[CWS][HEADER][COMPRESSED]` в `[FWS][HEADER2][UNCOMPRESSED]`, файл будет работать.
 - не затереть нуллбайт, закрывающий строку :)

Это конечно инженерная проктология, но плюсану за находчивость)